# broadcast action when cellular network is lost

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I need to detect when the Android lost the cellular network connection (i.e user active Airplane mode or user moves to a place where there aren't any cell tower).

Does Android (API 21 or higher) broadcast an intent when cellular network is lost?